# Wordpress custom header issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, default

I have created a template in wordpress for the home page, named: page-home-slider.php
I have chosen the home page to take that custom template.
Until here everything works fine.

Then I have created header-home.php, so a custom header for my home page.
Then in page-home-slider.php I have coded: get_header("home");

Now, when I access the home page from browser, the default header is displayed first and under it, my custom header. Is this normal? I wanted to have just my custom header. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

PS: I am using JobRoller template if it matters somehow.

[image: sample picture]

Comment: Is there a reason for not simply replacing the code in the header.php file with your header code instead of making a custom header file. That way you can simply call get_header(). What it looks like to me is that since the original header.php presumably still exists, it must be getting called somewhere. Without seeing your code there isn't a lot we can do though.

Comment: Can you please post the code of `page-home-slider.php`? It seems that `get_header()` is being called twice, the default first then your custom one. Please run a search in your theme directory to check where it's being called.

Comment: @RyanFitzgerald The reason is because I want to have a different header for my home page and a default one for the rest of the pages (yes, header.php exists). Is there a method to do this in header.php only?

Comment: @Aziz 
I cannot paste the code as it is too long, but I searched get_header() on it and it doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: @Catalin you can use an `if statement` in `header.php` that checks if the page matches your template: `if (is_page_template( 'page-home-slider.php' ) ) { ... }` see docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

Comment: @Catalin What I would suggest then is to find where get_header() is getting called currently, if it's showing up twice like that, it's more than likely because of that. If you find the currently get_header() and replace it with the call to your custom one, you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you guys! I have solved the problem using "is_page_template" as @Aziz suggested.

Comment: BTW There's a **WordPress SE** Q&A community => http://wordpress.stackexchange.com - you might consider posting there for future WordPress related questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you could set a condition in `header.php` that checks if the requested page has the template using the **`is_page_template()`** function:

**header.php**

```
if ( is_page_template( 'page-home-slider.php' ) )
{
   // do something different
}
```

Still, you need to check where `get_header()` is getting called to avoid duplicates.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/